# Refresh button not refreshing Custom Control values in Team Foundation Server 2013 Templates

Tags: tfs

We have recently migrated from Team Foundation Server 2010 to Team Foundation Server 2013 Update 2. In TFS 2013 template design we found the refresh form control (inbuilt control of TFS) which is unable to refresh the custom control values that is built by us. Is there any way that we can programatically modify to enable the refresh button work with custom control.

Please find below screenshot link for reference. 
http://postimg.org/image/z4mo3t8r9/

Comment: I would expect that the calls to the data are cached and you would need to refresh the browser. The purpose of the refresh button is to refresh the values of the fields, not the entire rendering of the work item.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

The refresh button is there to allow the data that populated the work item to be refreshed. The data that you want refreshed is part of the rendering of the form and would only be refreshed when the browser refreshes.